# I've done CSS changes but still no changes in frontend

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, firebug

I've made some `CSS` changes with Firebug's help, reagrding identifying what where the contents, meanwhile, although the result's changes when using firebug were exactly like i wanted, when editing the **child theme** **style.css** after updating, the frontend still remain the same... confirmed by Firebug.
My goal, is to make the `grid view` block adjustable to the `image`, similar to pinterest pictures display presentation.
The following code is what i've changed:

```
#content .category_grid_view {
margin:-10 0 20px -15px;
padding:0;
width:650px;
clear:both;
}
#content .category_grid_view li {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
float: left;
list-style: none outside none;
margin: -10 0 20px;
padding: 0 0 0 15px;
position: relative;
width: 200px;
}
#content .category_grid_view li.hr { 
display: none;
}
#content {
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
padding-left: 5px;
width: 640px;
}
#content .category_grid_view li a.post_img {
display: block;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding: 0;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 0 solid #E2DFDF;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 #DDDDDD;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}
```

This is the first that is happening to me... before, i used to make a `CSS` change the same way, and the impact was immedeatly.

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: not sure to have properly understood: you're doing some style modification using the firebug and you expect that those changes can permanently modify the css itself?

Comment: and what about your browser or server cache ?

Comment: No, after editing the child theme *style.css* in wp editor, and only after updating it. As all changes i've made before.

Comment: audre7... you're the MAN. I've cleared all the caches. And it's fine now. Beatifull. I forgot that i've been optimizing the website. And Cache issue was one of the improvements. Many thanks... how can i proceed to give you credits on this one? i'm noobie in here also.

Comment: Just FYI... If you made any changes to css for any websites - it may be plain html also, just flush your browser cache before accessing the site (you can do it by hitting ctrl+R to do a force refresh). Also, some hosts have server cache. If you are using any caching plugins (w3-total cache etc.) you have to clear server cache or disable those while making changes to the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a caching plugin, such as W3-Super-Cache, or a CDN such as Cloudflare? If so, you may need to clear your cache.

Also, your browser may be caching the CSS. Holding down Ctrl and pressing F5 clears the cache in most browsers ( or under browsers settings->clear cache ).

The third possibility is that your child theme's CSS is not loading for some reason.

**EDIT:** I see your question was answered in the comments above, but I also wanted to mention you can easily check if your theme's CSS is loading by inspecting the page with firebug, and looking to see that particular CSS file was loaded ( typically in the head ).

Answer (score 0):

i use chrome and i'm sure firefox is the same, but you should be able to see a list of css script files, select any one, and view its contents. if you updated an external css file (included in html with link tag), and refreshed web page with ctrl+f5 or fn+f5, all updated rules will be visible. in chrome you can check out every element and see what file styles are applied from, this should be the same as firefox